# Only allowing certain characters in string

Tags: php, string, function, filter

I have been looking for a way to create a function to check if a string contains anything other than lower case letters and numbers in it, and if it does return false. I have searched on the internet but all I can find is old methods that require you to use functions that are now deprecated in PHP5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check_input( $text ) {
  if( preg_match( "/[^a-z0-9]/", $text ) ) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex. Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match).

```
$matches = preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/', $string);
```

So now if `$matches` has `1`, you know the `$string` contains bad characters. Otherwise `$matches` is `0`, and the `$string` is OK.

Comment: Remember that this function can return false as well, so you should check it using the type comparison operator, `===`:

    $matches = preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/', $string);
    if($matches === 0) {
        // code here when it matches
    }

Answer (score 0):

To mixen things up a bit

```
<?
$input = "hello world 123!";
$digits = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");

if (ctype_alnum($input))
{
    if (ctype_lower(str_replace($digits, "", $input)))
    {
        // Input is only lowercase and digits
    }
}
?>
```

But regex is probably the way to go here! =)